# Invalid column count - Can't find the issue

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a large CSV with 200K rows that I am trying to import into a table with phpmyadmin. The column count of the table is exactly the same as the column count of CSV but I still get the error -

```
Invalid column count in CSV input on line 478.
INSERT INTO `ifsc` VALUES ('ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED', 'ABHY0065045', '400065045', 'KAMOTHE', 'DHARTI COMPLEX, SHOP NO.7,8,9310 & 11, PLOT NO. 60/61, SECTOR 18, KAMOTHE II, PANVEL-', '65298847', 'NAVI MUMBAI', 'RAIGAD', 'MAHARASHTRA')INSERT INTO `ifsc` VALUES ('ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED', 'ABHY0065046', '400065046', 'BHAYANDAR', 'SHOP NO. 7,8,9,&107 TO 111 ON GR. FLOOR & 1ST FLOOR. MALHAR ARCADE, CODDEV VILLAGE, NAVGHAR PHATAK ROAD, BHAYANDAR (E), DIST. THANE, 401101', '28140964', 'THANE', 'THANE', 'MAHARASHTRA')
```

When I directly run the SQl code shown in the error (after adding a semicolon before the second INSERT), it works fine.

Part of my table - https://pastebin.com/ER6BWBKy

```html
<table width="1259">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="64">ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td width="64">ABHY0065031</td>
<td width="64">4E+08</td>
<td width="64">NERUL</td>
<td width="683">ABHYUDAYA BANK BLDG. PLOT NO.3A, SECTOR 15, NERUL, NAVI MUMBAI-400706</td>
<td width="64">27717823</td>
<td width="64">MUMBAI</td>
<td width="64">GREATER MUMBAI</td>
<td colspan="2" width="128">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065032</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>AIROLI</td>
<td>ABHYUDAYA BANK BLDG., PLOT NO.26 SECTOR 17, AIROLI, NAVI MUMBAI-400701</td>
<td>27792043</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td>GREATER MUMBAI</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065034</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>ANDHERI</td>
<td>SHRADHA SHOPPING CENTRE, OLD NAGARDAS ROAD, ANDHERI (E), MUMBAI-400069</td>
<td>26833207</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td>GREATER MUMBAI</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065035</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>NHAVA SHEVA</td>
<td>J.N.P.T. SHOPPING COMPLEX, NHAVA SHEVA, NAVI MUMBAI-400707</td>
<td>27471237</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td>GREATER MUMBAI</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065036</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>BANKING COMPLEX</td>
<td>UNIT NO.7 SECTOR 19, PHASE II, APMC, VASHI, NAVI MUMBAI-400705</td>
<td>27830425</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td>GREATER MUMBAI</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065037</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>KOPARKHAIRNE</td>
<td>UNIT NO.1, PLOT 24-25 SECTOR 6, KOPARKHAIRANE, NAVI MUMBAI-400701</td>
<td>27544040</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td>GREATER MUMBAI</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065038</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>DADAR</td>
<td>GURUKRIPA CHS LTD., OPP. PLAZA CINEMA, DADAR (W), MUMBAI-400028.</td>
<td>24325136</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td>GREATER MUMBAI</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065039</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>MULUND</td>
<td>NEELKANTHDHARA, NETAJI SUBHASHCHANDRA ROAD, MULUND (W), MUMBAI-400080.</td>
<td>25641442</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td>GREATER MUMBAI</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065040</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>CHARAI</td>
<td>MUMBA DEVI APT., JOSHIWADA, CHARAI, VEER SAVARKAR PATH, THANE WEST 400601</td>
<td>25447077</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td>GREATER MUMBAI</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065041</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>LOKMANYA NAGAR</td>
<td>PANCHPAKHADI SAMARTHA CHS LTD., LOKMANYA NAGAR, THANE (W)-400608</td>
<td>25806049</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td>GREATER MUMBAI</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065042</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>KHARGHAR</td>
<td>SHOP NO 66/67, PATEL HERITAGE, PLOT NO 15/17, SECTOR 7, KHARGHAR, NAVI MUMBAI 410210</td>
<td>27741002</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td>RAIGAD</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065043</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>VASAI</td>
<td>OM SHIVSHAKTI COMPLEX, VAJRESHWARI ROAD, VALIV VILLAGE, VASAI ROAD (EAST), VASAI 401208</td>
<td>2452512</td>
<td>VASAI</td>
<td>THANE</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065044</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>GHANSOLI</td>
<td>SHREE MANOSHI COMPLEX, PLOT NO.5&amp; 6, SECTOR-3, GHANSOLI, NAVI MUMBAI GHANSOLI- 410 701.</td>
<td>27549124</td>
<td>NAVI MUMBAI</td>
<td>THANE</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065045</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>KAMOTHE</td>
<td>DHARTI COMPLEX, SHOP NO.7,8,9310 &amp; 11, PLOT NO. 60/61, SECTOR 18, KAMOTHE II, PANVEL-</td>
<td>65298847</td>
<td>NAVI MUMBAI</td>
<td>RAIGAD</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065046</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>BHAYANDAR</td>
<td>SHOP NO. 7,8,9,&amp;107 TO 111 ON GR. FLOOR &amp; 1ST FLOOR. MALHAR ARCADE, CODDEV VILLAGE, NAVGHAR PHATAK ROAD, BHAYANDAR (E), DIST. THANE, 401101</td>
<td>28140964</td>
<td>THANE</td>
<td>THANE</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065047</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>DAHISAR EAST</td>
<td>GR. FLOOR, MADHURAM HALL, HARISHANKAR JOSHI ROAD, DAHISAR (E), MUMBAI - 400 068</td>
<td>28480321</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td>GREATER MUMBAI</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065048</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>KALYAN-WEST</td>
<td>FLOWER VALLEY, KHADAKPADA, KALYAN (W), DIST. THANE 421 301</td>
<td>2203321</td>
<td>THANE</td>
<td>THANE</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065049</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>DOMBIVLI EAST</td>
<td>FIRST FLOOR, JAIKUL ARCADE, MANPADA ROAD, DOMBIVLI (E) 421201</td>
<td>2489860</td>
<td>THANE</td>
<td>THANE</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065050</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>OLD PANVEL</td>
<td>SHOP NO 1 &amp; 2, KANAK VITHAL, PLOT NO.25, OLD PANVEL, DIST RAIGAD 410 206</td>
<td>27459656</td>
<td>RAIGAD</td>
<td>RAIGAD</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065051</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>KANDIVALI (WEST)</td>
<td>KANDIVLI (W) BRANCH, SHOP NO.7, VIJAYBHARTI CO-OP. HSG. SOCIETY, SECTOR - II CHARKOP, KANDIVALI (W), MUMBAI 400067</td>
<td>28678031</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065052</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>MIRA ROAD (EAST)</td>
<td>SHOP NO. 6,7 &amp; 8, GROUND FLOOR, BUILDING NO. A-63, SECTOR - 1, SHANTI NAGAR, MIRA ROAD (E), DIST THANE 401107.</td>
<td>28555244</td>
<td>BHAYANDAR</td>
<td>THANE</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065053</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>BADLAPUR (EAST)</td>
<td>KULGAON GRIHNIRMAN SOCIETY, PLOT NO. 36, GANDHI CHOWK, NEAR KATDHARE HALL, KULGAON, BADLAPUR (E), DIST. THANE 421503</td>
<td>2693726</td>
<td>KALYAN</td>
<td>THANE</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED</td>
<td>ABHY0065054</td>
<td>4E+08</td>
<td>CHEMBUR</td>
<td>SHOP NO.12 TO 19, BLDG. NO. 2, TILAKNAGAR SHRAMIK CO-OP HSG SOCIETY LTD., TILAKNAGAR, CHEMBUR, MUMBAI 400089.</td>
<td>25262390</td>
<td>MUMBAI</td>
<td>GREATER MUMBAI</td>
<td colspan="2">MAHARASHTRA</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

There's no Apostrophe or quotes in the data.

Comment: Are you creating those INSERT statements manually, or where do they come from? Where does the actual reading of the CSV data happen?

Comment: @CBroe no, I am not creating them manually. I am using PHPMyAdmin's import page to import the CSV.ZIP file.

Comment: And you did specify all the settings according to how your CSV is structured? (delimiter, enclosure/escape sequence if applicable, etc.) Have you checked the mentioned line in your CSV file, and compared it with the ones before and after it?

Comment: @CBroe yes, I checked everything. 477 rows were successfully imported so I doubt it has anything to do with the settings. I checked the previous rows and they aren't different. You can check that on the sample table I attached.